# Scikit: Problem returning Dataframe from imputer instead of Numpy Array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

I am trying to impute some missing values in a Dataframe using the `scikit-learn` `IterativeImputer()`. The problem is that the imputer will take the `pandas` dataframe as an input, but will return a `numpy` array instead of the original dataframe. Here is a simple example taken from this [post](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/preprocessing_structured_data/impute_missing_values_with_means/).

```
# Create an empty dataset
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create two variables called x0 and x1. Make the first value of x1 a missing value
df['x0'] = [0.3051,0.4949,0.6974,0.3769,0.2231,0.341,0.4436,0.5897,0.6308,0.5]
df['x1'] = [np.nan,0.2654,0.2615,0.5846,0.4615,0.8308,0.4962,0.3269,0.5346,0.6731]

imputer = IterativeImputer(max_iter=10, random_state=42)
imputer.fit(df)
imputed_df = imputer.transform(df)
imputed_df
```

The problem is that when the `numpy` array is returned, the column names are removed and other metadata. I can of course manually extract that metadata from the original dataframe and then reapply it, but that seems a bit hacky. `Pandas` has its own imputer in terms of `Dataframe.fillna()` but the algorithms are not as sophisticated as the `scikit` ones.

So is there a way to fit the imputer to a dataframe and return a dataframe from the result.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes you can , just assign the values back

```
df[:]= imputer.transform(df)
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I wonder something so simple is not included in the `scikit` documentation, but this is very helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: this will drop all columns that didnt need to be imputed